# Name Backbone Model inside a collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is there a way to name the Backbone models inside the models collection? I'm trying to update a collection and need a way to make sure I am not duplicating the info.

```
Backbone.Collection {length: 1, models: Array[1], _byId: Object, on: function, once: function…}
_byId: Object
length: 1
models: Array[1]
  0: Backbone.Model //Name this guy
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Backbone.Collection
```

I'm setting it like this

```
this.app.user.get('Shipping').add(address);
```

Comment: @stakolee How would I do so? When I'm adding the info?

Comment: @stakolee, wait do you mean the unique cid that every model has? I can't use that because I am also trying to grab values based on what that model is named and they are all dynamically named.

Comment: you can specify which attribute the model will use for its unique id. 'cid' is created automatically for each distinct element. Can you update your question with some of the attributes for your existing models? More info: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute

Comment: It's going to be string coming from a different model so I can make sure the same models are not being passed in twice. I'm actually not looking to add another attributes to the models I'm setting, I'm looking for a way to set a name on the parent instead of  0: Backbone.Model to see if the 0 can be an id instead of the 0.